# Convert <T> into ViewModel

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I was wondering is it possible to solve this problem in a bit more generic way.

Give two viewmodels nearly identical, the difference is in the naming (e.g. public string Description and public string ReviewDescription)
There is a comparing function which works like this:

```
   private bool CompareTask(Models.Task model, TaskViewModel data)
        {
            bool same = false;
                    same = (model.Description == data.Description); // more compare
            return same;
        }
```

The question: is it possible - and if yes, how - to use generic for view model, something like this:

```
  private bool CompareTask<T>(Models.Task model, T data)
```

and create an if statement like:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(TaskViewModel)){ ... }
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(TaskReviewModel)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `IEquatable<T>`?

Implement it in your *view models* and *models*:

```
public class SomeViewModel : IEquatable<SomeModel>
{
    bool IEquatable<SomeModel>.Equals(SomeModel model)
        => model != null && SomeProperty == model.SomeOtherProperty;
}
```

Now, you can implement this method:

```
public bool AreEqual<T, S>(T a, S b)
     where T : class
     where S : class
{
    IEquatable<S> equatableToB = a as IEquatable<S>;

    return equatableToB != null && equatableToB.Equals(b);
}
```

You get a clear advantage with this approach: both a model or view model can be equatable with one or more classes:

```
public class SomeViewModel : IEquatable<SomeModel>, IEquatable<SomeOtherModel>
{
    bool IEquatable<SomeModel>.Equals(SomeModel model)
        => model != null && SomeProperty = model.SomeOtherProperty;


    bool IEquatable<SomeOtherModel>.Equals(SomeOtherModel model)
        => model != null && SomeOtherProperty = model.EvenSomeOtherProperty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, I'll go with @Matías-Fidemraizer solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `BaseViewModel` as BaseClass and implement a generic method this way:

```
 public class BaseViewModel
  {
     /// add members
  }

 public class TaskViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     /// add members
 }

 public class TaskReviewViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
    /// add members
 }


  private bool CompareTask<T>(Models.Task model)
            where T:BaseViewModel
  {
      var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            ....
  }
```

Comment: I could follow along until you did `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` - why, there is already a `T data` parameter?

Comment: @PeterB Agreed. it's not necessary .

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. The easiest way is to create base view model class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase { .. }
```

Then you can add a generic Method like :

```
ViewModelBase GetViewModel<T>() where T : ViewModelBase {

    // get or convert your viewmodel
    return (t) Convert.ChangeType(typeof(T), this.ViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your multiple TaskModel have same signature use an interface for the properties you want to compare.

Another method would be to implement the IEquatable to your other models and do something like this

```
public class Task
{
}

public class TaskViewModel : IEquatable<Task>
{
    public bool Equals(Task other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

private bool CompareTask<T>(Task model, T data)
        where T : IEquatable<Task>

    {
        return data.Equals(model);
    }
```